# java code to convert dollar to rupee

Tags: java, android, currency

Hi im working on an android app and i need to fetch the current value of 1 USD dollar in rupees from the internet using the link below or from any other website..

https://www.google.com/search?q=1+usd+in+inr&gws_rd=ssl

when i tried to parse the link using URL functions the whole html contents of the page are fetched..Can anyone help me fetch only the rupee value of 1 USD dollar in java..

Comment: Check if they have a webservice for that. Otherwise, you'll have to scrape the HTML.

Comment: You might google for "currency conversion web service" An example of one might be: http://fx.currencysystem.com/webservices/CurrencyServer4.asmx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898650/are-there-any-free-foreign-exchangex-rate-web-services

Comment: I'm surprised [**JodaMoney**](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/) doesn't have more options for currency.  It should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

use [this](http://www.freecurrencyconverterapi.com/api/v2/convert?q=USD_INR&compact=y) to get current USD to INR in json format:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.freecurrencyconverterapi.com/api/v2/convert?q=USD_INR&compact=y");
        BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String json=br.readLine();
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONObject valObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("USD_INR");
        System.out.println("Current USD to INR conversion is 1 USD = "+valObj.get("val")+ " INR");
```

prints

```
Current USD to INR conversion is 1 USD = 60.27 INR
```